# p2p ios devices connect. How find and connect devices

Tags: ios, sockets, p2p

I must develop simple p2p connect app.
I have:
1) database server and simple code server (php, nodejs or similar);
2) two ios devices.

How can I connected p2p between devices (for stream voice, text and photos)? Connect by IP and random port impossible, because devices may has same IP.
Devices can located on local network or different countries. Devices can has wi-fi or 3g/4g internet. Devices can stationed behind a router, NAT.

I know about openpeer and others SIP services. But it's very big and excessive solution. WebRTC not work in ios and webView. Multipeer connectivity framework is local devices only.
My question: how I can detect, uniquely identify devices and connect his?

I see this as:
1) On start app and has internet (wi-fi or 3g/4g) - application send message to server.
2) Server get from app: IP, UUID or other (I dont know what information is necessary and sufficient for p2p connect).
3) Server register app and device in DB and return now on-line devices list.
4) App get from server list of other devices.
5) User select other devices and click "connect".
6) Server send to two devices the necessary for connection information (IP's, UUID's and other).
7) Devices start connect p2p, receiving and transmitting data without using a server.

I see this arhitecture (openpeer) image:[image: openpeer arhitecture].
It is good. I must know HOW "finder" server detect devices and what data is necessary and sufficient for connect?
For me unacceptable using third-party servers for connect.

Please help me find the solution.

Comment: You have enough info about what you want to achieve. You also need to explain what have you tried so far. There are so many apps which do this already .. Try googling or searching on stackoverflow about this topic. Come up with some ideas at least. And when you get stuck at a particular question/implementation, then post a question.